# how to position a tooltip in qt graphicsview

Tags: qt, pyside

I want to show a tooltip when dragging the endpoint of a line to a QGraphicsItem with the mouse pointer (no hovering).

So i have the mouse event and i want to call QToolTip::showText(QPoint pt, String str) and i want to show the tooltip at a normal position relative to the mouse pointer.

But whatever i try (widget.mapToGlobal, item.mapToScene) on event.pos() the tooltip appears realtive to the topleft of my screen or the graphicsview, not the mouse.

Maybe i am missing something simple, but i would really appreciate some help with this.

```
widget = item.scene().views()[0] #there is only one view
p = event.pos()
pt = widget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(p.x(), p.y()))
QtGui.QToolTip.showText(pt, text)
```

Comment: Maybe try to use event.screenPos();

Comment: that did the trick! I'll put it as my own answer, because i cannot set your answer as the answer ...

Comment: Yes, because I posted this as comment, I just didn't want to post probably good or bad answer, so I wrote comment, now I can post this as answer, because I know that it is correct solution, it is normal practice for stackoverflow. You can upvote and accept my answer if it was helpful for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` has another useful method - `screenPos()` which returns the mouse cursor position in scene coordinates. Try to use it. For example:

```
QtGui.QToolTip.showText(event.screenPos(), text)
```